# Sudden spike in Centos free disk space

Tags: centos, hard-drive, quota

I have a VPS with 120GB of total disk capacity. In the past couple of months, our usage surged and since we have been within 95% of used disk space.

Anyhow, a couple of days ago, I've identified large logs files that were really not necessary and I removed them which bought me around 11 GB of space. The system showed 16GB of free space. But this morning, something interesting happened - I checked disk space only to find 26GB free. I can only assume that those were some tmp files.

Is there a way to determine which files were deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understanding exactly what is happening to your free space could involve a few methods:

- Previously recorded sizes such as with `ncdu -o` or any previous backups, running that again, and comparing.
- Any logs from log purge scripts. However, this logging may not exist, it is not typical to run for example `logrotate --verbose`.
- Guessing what was purged based on the oldest log files still there, when the purge is scheduled, and any recorded state like `/var/lib/logrotate/logrotate.status`.
- Evidence of closed deleted file handles. Unlink a log file that is still open, and the free space is not recovered until closed. Which might happen on a certain signal to the process, or restarting it.
- Identifying any not-log purges that may have happened, such as purging temporary files, caches, or reducing the size of databases.

Comment: Thank you, you were right. I did have log rotation in place and it rotated some rather large files. Why did log rotation allow those files to become so big... well... that is whole another question :)